# Update multiple columns with time() math

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table named `vips` with columns:

> user, timePayed, timeEnds, months

The user, timePayed and months are taking values as I want (meaning they working). Now what they have is user: username

> timePayed: time() (timestamp of when he payed)
>
> months: 1-7 (its a selection of buyer)

Now I tried to put a function every time my page loads to "refresh" the 'timeEnds' column. So my function have this inside:

```
 $timeNow = time();
 $query = DB::query("SELECT * FROM vips WHERE timeEnd='new';");
 $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    
 $months = $row['months'];
 $timePayed = $row['timePayed'];
 $payEnds = strtotime('+'.$months.' months +1', ($timePayed - $timeNow));
```

Now I want to add somehow this:

```
 DB::query("UPDATE vips SET timeEnd='$payEnds' WHERE timeEnd='$payEnds';");
```

For every column to update the column -> payEnds = months * timesPayed but I can't. Columns looks like this:

```
 user  timePayed   TimeEnds     months
 78 1408958750  new          2
 79 1408958752  new          6
 73 1408958904  new          8
```

And should be looking like:

```
 user  timePayed   TimeEnds     months
 78 1408958750  5350978      2
 79 1408958752  5350978      6
 73 1408958904  5350978      8
```

Example: 5350978 = will become this (I think even this is wrong:

```
 DB::query("UPDATE vips SET timeEnd='$payEnds' WHERE timeEnd='$payEnds';");
```

Comment: Please be careful not to overwrite good edits on your questions. @juergen improved it but you reverted those changes. This can sometimes happen during editing - make sure you watch out for a JavaScript pop-up that warns you the post has been edited. If you see this, it is best for new users to cancel the edit, refresh the page and edit again if necessary.

Comment: Are you just trying to search and replace 'new' with '5350978' in your `TimeEnds` column?

Comment: yes i am sure about the 'new' i insert it on another place
and i want to replace every

 'new' -> timePayed * months
about the edit part i was trying to edit the "code" part i have to sleep 2 days so excuse me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That approach would require multiple queries to run well.

Luckily MySQL was made for this so just run this query:

```
UPDATE vips 
SET timeEnds = UNIX_TIMESTAMP( (DATE_ADD( FROM_UNIXTIME(timePayed), INTERVAL months MONTH ) )) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())
```

Which means:

```
FROM_UNIXTIME(timePayed) 
    -> convert from unix time to MySQL date
DATE_ADD( FROM_UNIXTIME(timePayed), INTERVAL months MONTH )  
    -> find out the expiry date
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(...)
    -> we convert the whole expiry date back to integer, for easier math
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())
    -> we see how much time is left between now and the expiry date
```

Downsides:

- `NOW()` is not replication-friendly
- not scalable, running this on 1000000 records on each request will be bad
- may be a refactoring issue if you ever decide to use a view and a table instead of just this table

If it's a small thing you can leave it this way, but if you want to do a bigger thing sometimes, you should only calculate `timeEnds` when you need it.

Comment: solved. thank you for the info its small query about 10-20 values each time. i will consider rebuild it later as you advised.